# Custo de processamento entre código e banco de dados

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho

Entre as tantas formas de desenvolvimento, ficou uma duvida sobre o que ira consumir mais do meu processamento entre a mesma operação de diferentes formas...

Se eu tenho uma função que pode ser feita direta no meu banco de dados (um `insert` utilizando um `select` como um exemplo básico)

```
Insert into Tabela1(Coluna1,2Coluna,3_coluna) select (select cod from tabela3 where tabela3.nome = tabela2.nome)as 'Coluna1',valorx,valory from Tabela2  Tabela2.cod=z
```

e a mesma função pode ser feita através do meu código

```
 MySqlCommand mySqlCommand_Select = new MySqlCommand("Busca valores tabela2", mySqlConnection);

MySqlCommand mySqlCommand_Select_2 = new MySqlCommand("Busca valores tabela3", mySqlConnection);

//...
//Unir Selects, trabalha os valores etc
//...

 MySqlCommand mySqlCommand_insert = new MySqlCommand("Insere os valores tabela1", mySqlConnection);
```

Sendo o processo realizado o mesmo, o custo é maior pra um ou outro ou é igual?

A pergunta inclui outras operações que podem ser feitas diretamente no banco e/ou código (como cálculos, outras *queries* utilizadas como sub ou como varias buscas) mas se resume ao custo de 'Terceirizar' ou não estas operações para minha aplicação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só dá para responder isso caso a caso, ou seja só medindo com *queries*, otimizações disponíveis, carga de dados e carga de acesso reais. O que vale em uma circunstância não vale para outra.

De qualquer forma as duas *queires* serão executadas no banco de dados, então a premissa da pergunta é falsa. Estou considerando que a *query* será a mesma usada no SQL puro.

Sem maiores detalhes, sem saber que otimizações são possíveis eu diria que o custo é mesmo. Desconheço se o MySQL tem alguma otimização específica que pode fazer um deles ser mais rápido.

Deve ter uma diferença marginal insignificante, espacialmente se tiver muitos dados.

Se as *queries* são diferentes está comparando laranjas com bananas e o resultado não é útil.

No caso parecem diferentes já que uma está fazendo tudo de uma vez e a outra está fazendo em três partes distintas. Aí não é tanto questão de fazer no banco de dados ou não, é o fato de serem consultas separadas.

O fato de estar iniciando pelo código só potencializa o problema porque vários dados farão viagens entre a aplicação e o banco de dados sem necessidade. Mas novamente isto só ocorre porque a *query* é outra, não porque foi iniciada na aplicação.

Comment: Apesar de eu mesmo notar que não esta muito bem explicado foi a melhor forma que encontrei, mas acredito que esta resposta seja uma grande variante entre os casos, ainda assim, oq eu quis perguntar foi sobre os custos de coisas como grandes cálculos e formulas por exemplo, o melhor seria trazer estes dados para meu sistema ou posso trabalhar com eles ainda no sql(ainda falando sobre custo de processamento)

Comment: @LeoLonghi, analisando a pergunta de acordo com sua argumentação aqui. Não ficou claro qual era seu objetivo, acredito que devido a isso, foi essa resposta que obteve.